# how to keep jquery mobile header and footer fixed?

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am making a website using jQuery Mobile.

How to keep jquery mobile header and footer fixed? I just want only the content to scroll(just like it happens in iPhone applications), and keep the headers and footers fixed at top and bottom.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 29):

Add this attribute to your header/footer div:

```
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Header Page 1</h1>
        </div>
```

Also, you might have a look at this:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Comment: this wont work in iPhone and iPad but will work in Android stuff.

Comment: dude, this is a post from early 2010 (and long before the final 1.0 release).. in iOS 5 on iDevices there became a possibility for css position fixed (pre iOS 5 the position was calculated by jqmobile, faded out and in again when scrolling)

Comment: Have to say, my results with `data-position="fixed"` on the BB10 have been...mixed. It was better after using the viewport tag found [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-set-up-the-viewport-for-a-BlackBerry-WebWorks-application/ta-p/1943807) - not the fancy JS based on mind!, but it's still not 100%. And this is in 2013.

Answer (score 4):

The issue I had with jquery mobile fixed is that the header and footer fade.  I imagine this is something that they will correct in the future but in addition to [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) suggested by Dan, there is also jquery mobile scrollview and wink toolkit.  I had good results with jquery mobile scrollview but no luck with iscroll or wink

1) Jquery mobile Scrollview

- Demo: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/
- Code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview/

2) Wink Toolkit

- Tutorial: http://www.winktoolkit.org/tutorials/119/
- Demo: http://www.winktoolkit.org/documentation/wink/ui/layout/scroller/test/test_scroller4.html?theme=default

Comment: Did anyone test this on an iOS device; because for me the screen is just stuck and when i keep swiping, eventually the toolbars stills fade in/out... I'm specifically talking about Jquery mobile.

Comment: I used jquery mobile scrollview on iOS.  It worked fine.  That being said, I eventually switched to sencha touch.  Jquery mobile performance was too poor (delay with every button click) and lacked essential controls.  Perhaps it has improved now.   It is definitely more fun to program with.

Comment: If you bind to "tap" and "touchstart" events instead of "click," the delay goes away.

Comment: Link 1 Demo and Link 2 Demo are deads :S

Answer (score 2):

Another option is check out iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Answer (score 1):

To enable this toolbar feature type, you apply the data-fullscreen="true" attribute and the data-position="fixed" attribute to both the header and footer div elements. The framework will also unset the padding for the content container (ui-content)

```
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
        <h1>Header Page 1</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html (jquery.mobile.scrollview.js, scrollview.js, and easing.js) and put data-scroll="true" in the page div tag as suggested here: [scrollview for jQuery mobile tollbars *not* to be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935693/scrollview-for-jquery-mobile-tollbars-not-to-be-fixed) .

Worked well for me thus far.

Cheers,

E

Answer (score 0):

Use iScroll v4. Keep header and footer fixed and scroll only the content. iScroll needs a wrapper DIV and child element. In the example below the content_items is the child div with the items to scroll. I noticed that you can not combine the data-role="content" and the wrapper DIV for iScroll in one HTML element!.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myScroll;

$(document).ready(function () {

    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');

});

</script>
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div id="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
    <div id="content" data-role="content" class="contentcontainer contentsearched">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content_items" class="content_items"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you try the latest jquery-mobile version (1.1.0-rc). it fixed this bug.

have a look [here](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6, 7 and 8, this hack seems to solve the problem and trigger a redraw to correctly replace the fixed header (with or without panel) on iPod, iPhone and iPad. Note: We test for iOS device and only add this event in that case *.

```
if (iOS()) {
    $(document).on('blur', 'input:not(:submit), select, textarea', function () {
        var paddingBottom = parseFloat($(".ui-mobile-viewport, .ui-page-active").css("padding-bottom"));
        $(".ui-mobile-viewport, .ui-page-active").css("padding-bottom", (paddingBottom + 1) + "px");
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(".ui-mobile-viewport, .ui-page-active").css("padding-bottom", paddingBottom + "px");
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

* Test for iOS:

```
var iOS() = function () {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (/iphone|ipad|ipod/).test(userAgent);
}
```