# scrollview for jQuery mobile tollbars *not* to be fixed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I have been using scrollview (http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/) successfully for an image gallery left/right swipe (which looks great) however the header/footer are always persistent and I cant work out looking at the code or looking online a way for these to be inline rather then fixed (like the default jQuery mobile setup).

Any ideas? Or have I missed something obvious?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">` into `<div data-role="header">` in your html
and it should be enough.

[edit]

Ok, It's not enough.

Scrollview plugin scrolls the area of a HTML element that it's applied to, so to scroll the whole page instead of a div in the content, you would have to put `data-scroll="true"` attribute in the page div.

I hereby declare, that I didn't test if it is supported by the scrollview plugin. ;)

Comment: Hi. I havent got a fixed data position in the mark-up. Scrollview js seems to be fixing it via js/css itself as far as I can tell...

Comment: In the demos it was there. Please link to a demo of what you have.

Comment: Hi. That doesnt seem to affect the sticky/fixed toolbar issue? I have been looking at iScroll 4 and this seems to do the trick fine

Comment: scrollview isn't using scrolling mechanizms at all, it works with HTML node's overflows. If you can't make it work on any of the elements containing the header, then the header will not be scrolled. If you find out how to do it with anything else, please post that info as an answer to your own question.