# Adding element dynamically in jquerymobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When i am appending the `element (position : absolute)` dynamically at run time in the

```
content part  (data-role=content)
```

of  JqueryMobile Page , the `footer` will not set according to the height of

the newly added element.Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please post some code or create a JSFiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of reasons, can't tell you much without looking at your code.

For instance, do you have the latest JQuery mobile version?

Right now my guess is that you aren't doing anything to let the footer know that a new element has been added dynamically. In my own implementation the latest version of JQuery mobile solves this problem, however take a look at other solution such as: [how to keep jquery mobile header and footer fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724068/how-to-keep-jquery-mobile-header-and-footer-fixed)

In here iScroll is used as a plausible solution. You may also look at: [scrollview for jQuery mobile tollbars *not* to be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935693/scrollview-for-jquery-mobile-tollbars-not-to-be-fixed)