# jQuery Mobile: Stick footer to bottom of page

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Is there any way, bearing in mind the way the jQuery Mobile framework operates, to fix the page so that the footer always aligns with the bottom of the page - no matter the height.

As it stands the height of a jQuery page will change, especially as devices are rotated portrait to landscape, so the solution would have to take this into account.

Just to clarify - I don't need the footer to be at the bottom of viewport, just working so that the default page height doesn't drop below the viewport height.

Thanks.

Comment: this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724068/how-to-keep-jquery-mobile-header-and-footer-fixed

Comment: that worked for me too. it seems the top answer is out of date ?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can add this in your css file:

```
[data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;}
[data-role=footer]{bottom:0; position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; width:100%;}
```

So the page data-role now have 100% height, and footer is in absolute position.

Also Yappo have wrote an excellent plugin that you can find here:
jQuery Mobile in a iScroll plugin
http://yappo.github.com/projects/jquery.mobile.iscroll/livedemo.html

hope you found the answer!

> **An answer update**

You can now use the `data-position="fixed"` attribute to keep your footer element on the bottom.
Docs and demos: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/toolbar-fixed/

Comment: This fixed the problem for PC-sized displays. However, on mobiles, now the footer sticks about halfway through the page. Therefore, I do not think that this solution works. However, I do like the CSS-only approach.

Comment: Tried this and the footer stuck to the bottom of the screen until I tried scrolling.  The footer moved along with everything else.  The Yappo link did seem to work, though.

Comment: @KevinSchroeder Nice you found Yappo's solution working! jQuery Mobile has update the plugin and i don't know the reason it's not working at your project. What version you run?

Comment: yappo.github.com doesn't work in chrome, only thing i looked at it in. items don't scroll at all.

Comment: I prefer position:fixed for a footer that I expect to always be available at the bottom.

Comment: This did not work well for me at all (neither the code or the Yappo demo page).  I posted an answer on this thread of the solution I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377016/jquery-mobile-sticky-footer/12828302#12828302

Comment: Thanks @Nick, this question is 1 year old and since that time a lot of updates came up. I suggest to use the latest dev version that fix this problem.

Comment: When i am using dynamic contant footer is going down it is not at fixed position plz suggest me some way.

Comment: This answer is obsolete - check the solution below

Comment: An updated answer doesn't work for Windows Phone, however it works fine in Android and iOS.

Answer (score 62):

Since this issue is kind of old a lot of things have changed.

You can now get this behavior by adding this to the footer div

```
data-position="fixed"
```

More info here:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

**Also beware, if you use the previously mentioned CSS together with the new JQM solution you will NOT get the appropriate behavior!**

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, using jquerymobile 1.7+

Comment: The only annoying part about this is that it constantly seems to float over top of your content rather than just going to the bottom when there is not much content to fill the gaps.

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee: "using jquerymobile 1.7+"...quite a soothsayer you are...:P

Comment: *Ahem* - not sure if this was a compliment :)

Comment: On windows phone 8.0 JQM/PG projects, there's a ~50px gap, which you can fix with media queries, but still a few pixels where lists 'underflow' behind the footer :-(...

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I needed to use something like this to keep the footer pinned down at the bottom if there is not much content, but not floating on top of everything constantly like [`data-position="fixed"`](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) seems to do...

```
.ui-content
{
    margin-bottom:75px; /* Set this to whatever your footer size is... */
}

.ui-footer {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Best css-only solution IMHO

Comment: +1. Otherwise the footer hides part of the page content when there's not enough space.

Answer (score 5):

> [Fixed basics](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/toolbar-fixed/)
>
> To enable this behavior on a header or footer, add the
>   `data-position="fixed"` attribute to a jQuery Mobile header or footer
>   element.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Footer!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

jQm offers:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/bars-fullscreen.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

None of these work?

Comment: Not in the way I would like. Basically the page will only ever extend to the height of the content, so on a desktop machine with a large resolution, the footer will sit halfway up the screen. id like it to be intelligent enough to expand to fill the extra space.

Comment: I thought they fixed that with the beta version, if not you could always use css to fix the page height:100%

Answer (score 2):

The following lines work just fine...

```
var headerHeight = $( '#header' ).height();
var footerHeight = $( '#footer' ).height();
var footerTop = $( '#footer' ).offset().top;
var height = ( footerTop - ( headerHeight + footerHeight ) );
$( '#content' ).height( height );
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd share my CSS only solution here. This way you can avoid the extra overhead of using JS for this.

This isn't a fixed position footer. The footer will be offscreen if the page content is taller than the screen. I think it looks better this way.

The body and .ui-page min-height and height are necessary to prevent the footer from jumping up and down during transitions.

Works with the latest JQM version as of now, 1.4.0

```
body,
.ui-page {
    min-height:100% !important;
    height:auto !important;
}

.ui-content {
    margin-bottom:42px; /* HEIGHT OF YOUR FOOTER */
}

.ui-footer {
    position:absolute !important;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: it did not work for me, but jocull's even simpler/reduced CSS solution worked fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14669899/1915920

Comment: This work for me (JQM 1.4.5) and jocull's solution also work but it has  jumping problem while resizing the browser in my test case. ArcadeRenegade's is smooth! BTW. Don't mix with data-position="fixed" it cause confuse...

Answer (score 1):

This script seemed to work for me...

```
$(function(){
    checkWindowHeight();
    $(document).bind('orientationchange',function(event){
        checkWindowHeight();
    })
});

function checkWindowHeight(){
        $('[data-role=content]').each(function(){
        var containerHeight = parseInt($(this).css('height'));
        var windowHeight = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
        if(containerHeight+118 < windowHeight){
            var newHeight = windowHeight-118;
            $(this).css('min-height', newHeight+'px');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the data-position="fixed" and adding the below style in the css will fix the issue   z-index: 1;

Answer (score 0):

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

You could possibly use this and use jQuery to update the css height of the elements to make sure it stays in place.