# Sticky Footer W/JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used a tutorial for a sticky footer. It worked, but I then added JQuery Mobile and it no longer works. Here is a jfiddle (doesn't work ). Unclick the use of the Jquery mobile extension and it does what I want. How can I get the functionality I had with the use of Jquery mobile?

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/CTjZs/15/

It uses the basic sticky footer structure...

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        content
    </div>
</div>

<div id="addfooter">
</div>
```

Thank you for taking the time to consider my question.

Comment: in FF is sticky as it can be!

Comment: @roXon Even with jquery mobile enabled? I am using my droid and a chrome browser, both lock the footer to the bottom of the window but it is not in the view at all times.

Comment: Take a look at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/fixed-toolbars/ and see if it's a viable alternative..

Comment: @asifrc yes thank you that is what I was looking for. When no onclick action is assigned to my footer; it clicks what is behind that footer. It works when I assign action to my footer. Is there something you know of I should do to deactivate the action behind the footer or is simply assigning an onclick action to my footer going to be sufficient?

Comment: @Four_lo I posted my link as answer so future visitors have easy access. Unfortunately, I don't know about the onclick thing without taking a look. Perhaps if you could post a jsfiddle of it. It probably would be best to post as a separate question, and chances are it'll get better attention, a better answer than I might provide, and might help someone who runs into the problem later on..

Comment: @Four_lo btw, if you do post it as another question, it'd be helpful for me and maybe others if you posted a link to the new question here so we can find it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile has a native footer that supports a fixed, or 'sticky', position. An example and documentation can be found at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/fixed-toolbars/