# Sticky-Footer for jQueryMobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, sticky-footer

The best way to describe what I'm looking for is the thread below.

[Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)

The difference is I want a footer like stackoverflow at the bottom but using the jQueryMobile framework.  Is this possible?

I've tried the techniques in the other thread successfully for sites not using the framework, but I think the framework forces divs into absolute position and it gets really messy and I'm not sure the best way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want the footer to be visible all the time or you want it appear only at the end of the page,

Comment: only at the end of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

```
[data-role=page] {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
[data-role=content] {
  margin-bottom: 80px; /* based on how tall your footer is and how much gap you want */
}
[data-role=footer] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px /* this can be configurable, or omitted, as long as the above padding-bottom is at least as much as the height of the footer is */
  padding-bottom:60px;
}
```

I did a variation of the answer I found by Nick here:  [Jquery Mobile Sticky Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377016/jquery-mobile-sticky-footer)

What I changed was to use margin instead of padding so that the content didn't increase in size when there was no need for it to.