# jquery mobile footer on the bottom

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've a CSS style for my footer in a jquery mobile app:

```
[data-role=footer]{
    bottom:0px; 
    position: relative !important; 
    top: auto !important; 
    width:100%;
}
```

Now I want that the footer is always at the bottom of the page, including the case that the content is higher then the page so I have to scroll. 
Look and feel should be similar to a normal website, opened in safari on iOS.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861764/jquery-mobile-stick-footer-to-bottom-of-page?rq=1) does not help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jquery-mobile to create a [**fixed footer**](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) just do:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
your footer data
</div>
```