# iScrollview - JQuery mobile problems

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscroll

I am currently trying to build a Facebook-styled web App using jQuery mobile. My main problem is that users are not able to scroll both navigation-bar and content at the same time. I tried many css based solutions but whereas my normal browser displays everything correct all my mobile devices refuse to display two scroll bars at the same time.

So I tried to implement `iScroll` with `iScrollview`. It works just perfectly with every content but with my slideable menu-bar. I have no idea where the problem might be. As soon as a page is added `iScrollview` seems to ignore the `data-iscroll` attribute.

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport">
<div id="menu" data-role="content" data-iscroll> <!--Menu-->
  <div id="memberDetails">
    <h3>Username</h3>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="menuDivider" >MENUDIVIDER</li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="contentLink" data-transition="none"><span class="icon" id="home"></span><span class="text">Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page1" class="contentLink" data-transition="none" data-prefetch><span class="icon" id="page1"></span><span class="text">Page One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2" class="contentLink" data-transition="none" data-prefetch><span class="icon" id="page2"></span><span class="text">Page Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3" class="contentLink" data-transition="none" data-prefetch><span class="icon" id="page3"></span><span class="text">Page Three</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page8" class="contentLink" data-transition="none" data-prefetch><span class="icon" id="page8"></span><span class="text">Page Eight</span></a></li>
    <li class="menuDivider" >MENUDIVIDER</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--/Menu--> 

<!--page Home-->

<div data-role="page" class="pages ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" id="home" data-url="home" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: 0px; min-height: 882px; ">
  <div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"> <a href="#" class="showMenu menuBtn" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ui-btn-text">Menu</span></span></a>
    <h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">Home</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->
  <div id="logo"><img src="files/images/wig_logo.png" alt="wig-logo" width="54" height="25"></div>
  <!-- /logo -->
  <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /content --> 
</div>
<!-- /page Home-->
</body>
```

I am using jQuery 1.8.2, JQM 1.2.0. The `slideeffect` is done by basically setting the content's margin to the menu's width. Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: fixed header works in new iOS 5 and 6. If your users are from old user base then you gotta worry about fixed navigation bar. I too had similar question once. See here this will help you if your users are above iOS 4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945966/fixed-header-jquery-mobile

Comment: i didnt find any solution for this problem but i at least found another plugin - [link](https://github.com/tegansnyder/JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu)